# showing Div inside td of a table is not reactive using Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a table that the last column is a div where I have three options (View, Edit and delete). This sub menu is always hidden, but when I click in the options button that is the last column of my table, the array that I use to control what is showing is updated to true (it should be showing), but nothing happened in my page.

Here is my HTML code

```
<td class="kt-datatable__cell">
    <span style="overflow: visible; position: relative; width: 197px;">
        <center>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon btn-icon-md" @click="toggleHover(index)"
                 v-bind:class="{'show': hover[index]}">
                    <i class="flaticon2-shield"></i>
                </a>
                <div v-bind:class="{'show': hover[index]}" class="dropdown-menu">
```

And here is my method that I call using `@click`

```
methods: {
    toggleHover(index) {
        this.hover[index] = !this.hover[index];
    }
```

If I set true for a random position right after I get the data from the server, it shows, but when I try to change this by clicking, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's  a [`reactivity caveat`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), so you should do :

```
methods: {
    toggleHover(index) {
        this.$set(this.hover,index , !this.hover[index]);
    }
```